# Display Associative array in awk

Tags: awk, array

How can I display Associative array, when I don't know index?
My script:

```
{
tab[$1]=tab[$1]+1
}
END{
print tab[*]#display array -> it doesn't work
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
a
b
b
c
c
c
```

To get the keys of an associative array in awk, we use a `for` loop of the form `for (key in arrayname) action`.  For example:

```
$ awk '{tab[$1]=tab[$1]+1} END{for (key in tab)print key, tab[key]}' file
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

Note that, in POSIX awk, this loop is not guaranteed to return the keys of the associative array in any particular order.